# Trying to loop append a list outside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to complete the loop below where inputs are taken from the user and then sent through the function "shipPlacement" at the top. However, when i run my code, the loop runs for the first term in "shipSizeList" and then after completing the function the user is not prompted for another input for "inputPos". How do i design this so all the differently sized ships positions are appended to "listOfShipsPos"?

```
listOfShipsPos = []

# adds to the grid where all of the ships are
def shipPlacement(position,size,direction):
    listOfShipsPos.append(position)
    direction.upper()
    i = 1
    # for the length of ship (size), repeats adding positions in the
    # desired direction (up(U), down(D), left(L) or right(R))
    while i < size:
        if direction == "U":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship - 8)
        if direction == "D":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship + 8)
        if direction == "L":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship - 1)
        if direction == "R":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship + 1)
        i =+ 1


# ask user to input their ship positions
shipSizeList = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
for shipSize in shipSizeList:
    inputSize = shipSize
    inputPos = int(input("Position for " + str(shipSize) + " sized ship? (1 to 64)"))
    inputDir = str(input("direction for " + str(shipSize) + " long ship? "))
    shipPlacement(position=inputPos, size=inputSize, direction=inputDir)
```

Comment: Augmented assignment would be ´a += 1´. Your statement ´a =+ 1´ is the same as ´a = +1´ or just ´a = 1´.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `shipPlacement` actually never finishes executing because the loop never completes. The reason is the statement `i =+ 1`. It should be `i += 1`. Also, I think you should reassign the variable `direction`, this is the full code

```
listOfShipsPos = []

# adds to the grid where all of the ships are
def shipPlacement(position,size,direction):

    listOfShipsPos.append(position)
    direction = direction.upper()
    i = 1
    # for the length of ship (size), repeats adding positions in the
    # desired direction (up(U), down(D), left(L) or right(R))
    while i < size:

        if direction == "U":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship - 8)
        if direction == "D":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship + 8)
        if direction == "L":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship - 1)
        if direction == "R":
            listOfShipsPos.append(ship + 1)
        i += 1


# ask user to input their ship positions
shipSizeList = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
for shipSize in shipSizeList:
    inputSize = shipSize
    inputPos = int(input("Position for " + str(shipSize) + " sized ship? (1 to 64)"))
    inputDir = str(input("direction for " + str(shipSize) + " long ship? "))
    shipPlacement(position=inputPos, size=inputSize, direction=inputDir)
```